# How can I fix Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

[image]

I have problem using pod. How can I solve this problem with Podfile when run "pod install"?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?